# HTTPPOST in MVC not returning view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

A simple action method when called with httppost attribute not returning view.but with post perfectly working. Just 2 days back I started learning MVC. For learning purpose I made a simple action to return a view with httppost but it dint work. i searched in forums too but dint get clear idea.. can anybody explain..

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult login(LoginModel loginmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


        }

        return View();

   }
```

My view:

```
<h2>login</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.username)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.username)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username)
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant action methdod?

Comment: Which action displays the form? Is it also named login?

Comment: Do you have both a get and a post action?

Comment: actually am in learning phase.. so when i used get the view is rendered in browser.. but when i used httppost  i dint get that view..am getting page not found error.. i cant understand y..

Comment: Can you please also post your `LoginModel` class and the name of the controller that this login method is in?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the viewmodel back to the view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult login(LoginModel loginmodel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      // to do : check login and redirect
    }
    // validation failed. let's return to the view.
    return View(loginmodel);
}
```

Comment: is it hitting the HttpPost action method ? Is your GET view's name is also "Login.cshtml" ?

Comment: use visual studio break points to see where the control goes ? May be inside the IsValid if condition, It is redirecting to an action method which does not exist

Comment: it is not even hits the breakpoint.. i put a break point on httppost and if condition.. i dont understand why it is not even calling the action..

Comment: what is the name of your view which has the login form ?

Comment: login.cshtml is the view

Comment: is your GET view strongly typed tp `LoginModel` ? Does your `LoginModel ` properties like `username` ?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments from @Shyju's answer you state that you are receiving a 404 error message when you submit the form. This indicates to me that the form's action doesn't have the correct URL. This isn't too surprising as the ASP.NET MVC framework is picking the URL based on some assumptions.

Change the the from declaration in your view to explicitly defined the action name and controller name of your HttpPost login action.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("login", "MyControl"))
```

*Replace* `"MyControl"` *with the actually name of your controller.*

Comment: I tried no luck..as I told i get the page when there is no httppost. that means  httppost is making some difference in the view rendering. i just want to know that.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your Controller and Action name in Form like

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller"))
```

And then you need to return the Model in view like

```
    return view(model)
```

Hope it will help you.